# Connect python to Sybase IQ

Tags: python, sap-iq

First of all thank you for your help.

I was trying to retrieve some data from a sybase IQ database using python, but I can not make it.

I've tried with the following code( from https://github.com/sqlanywhere/sqlanydb):

```
import sqlanydb
conn = sqlanydb.connect(uid='dba', pwd='sql', eng='demo', dbn='demo' )
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute("select 'Hello, world!'")
print( "SQL Anywhere says: %s" % curs.fetchone() )
curs.close()
conn.close()
```

Unfotunately it gives me the following error:

```
InterfaceError: ('Could not load dbcapi.  Tried: None,dbcapi.dll,libdbcapi_r.so,libdbcapi_r.dylib', 0)
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Jessica

Answer (score 2):

On windows, first you need to add the data source name (DSN).

You do this by searching for 'odbc data source administrator' on windows and creating a DSN for 'SQL Anywhere 12'. Fill in the necessary information like username,password,host,port,server name and database name. Finally test the connection as shown.

[image]

Once finished you can call the code as follows:

```
import sqlanydb

conn = sqlanydb.connect(dsn='SYBASE_IQ')
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute("select 'Hello, world!'")
print( "SQL Anywhere says: %s" % curs.fetchone())
curs.close()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Get and install the SYBASE ODBC DRIVER.
2. Configure the DSN on your PC.

On Windows, search for the Microsoft ODBC Administrator. Then create a DSN.

[image: Select the driver]

[image: Configure DSN attributes]

3. Python code:

   - using SQLAchemy

     ```
     import sqlalchemy as sa
     from sqlalchemy import create_engine, event
     from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL
     import urllib

     params = urllib.parse.quote_plus('DSN=dsn_name;PWD=user_pwd')
     engine = sa.create_engine("sybase+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(params))

     with engine.connect() as cursor:

          cursor.execute(""" SELECT * FROM database """)
     ```
   - Using PyODBC

     ```
     import pyodbc

     conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=dsn_name;PWD=user_pwd')

     with conn:
          cursor = conn.cursor()   
          cursor.execute(""" SELECT * FROM database """)
     ```